# ICanHaz.js name each li in a ul?

Tags: jquery, icanhaz.js

I am using icanhaz.js templates and I was wondering if anyone knew if it was possible to give a class name to each `<li>` within a list created by the template?

for example:

```
 <script id="testLI" type="text/html">
      <li class="list-1">
        <p>Name: {{ name }}</p>
        <p>Here Now: {{ count }}</p>
        <p>ID: {{ id }}</p>
      </li>
  </script>
```

If I could have each `<li>` have a class of 'list-1', 'list-2', 'list-3', and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you are implementing. But you should loop through your data and in you loop have a counter. Increase the counter each time and place in {{index}}.

```
<script id="testLI" type="text/html">
  <li class="list-{{index}}">
    <p>Name: {{ name }}</p>
    <p>Here Now: {{ count }}</p>
    <p>ID: {{ id }}</p>
  </li>
</script>
```

Example Loop

```
for (var i = 1; i < data_var.length; i++) {
  var data = {
    index: i,
    name: "name",
    count: "count",
    id: "id"
  }
  // Do whatever you need with data.
  // html = ich.listLI(data)
}
```